# How can I create a form that posts the results direct on the page and has character limitations?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, submit

I am creating a simple Name & Comment form that posts the results direct on the page, and erases on refresh. One input box can only be certain characters. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = "";
$name = $comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
?>
```